# Contact Form Mixed Up

Tags: html, css, forms

My "Reason for Contacting" and "Comment" boxes seem to be flipped and on different lines.

```css
label {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 10em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-left: 6em;
}

form {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  <p>Required fields are marked with an asterisk *</p>
  <form>
    <label for="myName">*Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="myName" name="myName" required="required">
    <label for="myEmail">*E-mail: </label>
    <input type="email" id="myEmail" name="myEmail" required="required">
    <label for="myPhone">Phone: </label>
    <input type="tel" id="myPhone" name="myPhone">
    <label for="reason">*Reason For Contacting:</label>
    <select class="reason">
      <option value="join">Interest in Joining</option>
      <option value="sponsor">Sponsorship</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <label for="myComments">Comments:</label>
    <textarea id="myComments" name="myComments" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your css I can see that you have given `float: left` to the `label`. So, the `label` floats left, leaving space on the right for the next element. But, the `input` is given `display: block`, which occupies the whole remaining place to right.

But the `select` element is `display: inline` by default. Hence, they seem to be mixed up. Just add `display: block` to select too.

```css
label {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 10em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

select,/* add this */
input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-left: 6em;
}

form {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  <p>Required fields are marked with an asterisk *</p>
  <form>
    <label for="myName">*Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="myName" name="myName" required="required">
    <label for="myEmail">*E-mail: </label>
    <input type="email" id="myEmail" name="myEmail" required="required">
    <label for="myPhone">Phone: </label>
    <input type="tel" id="myPhone" name="myPhone">
    <label for="reason">*Reason For Contacting:</label>
    <select name="reason" class="reason">
      <option value="join">Interest in Joining</option>
      <option value="sponsor">Sponsorship</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <label for="myComments">Comments:</label>
    <textarea id="myComments" name="myComments" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is because you have labels set to `float: left;` and elements that have no floats set at all so it's disrupting the flow.

Easiest way to fix this is to break elements up into `fieldsets`.

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

label {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 10em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-left: 6em;
}

form {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  <p>Required fields are marked with an asterisk *</p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="myName">*Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="myName" name="myName" required="required">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="myEmail">*E-mail: </label>
    <input type="email" id="myEmail" name="myEmail" required="required">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="myPhone">Phone: </label>
    <input type="tel" id="myPhone" name="myPhone">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="reason">*Reason For Contacting:</label>
    <select class="reason">
      <option value="join">Interest in Joining</option>
      <option value="sponsor">Sponsorship</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="myComments">Comments:</label>
    <textarea id="myComments" name="myComments" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```